# Send a tcp request from PHP Website to JAVA program

Tags: java, php, sockets, send

I want to send a TCP Request from my website to my java application. So my java application should be able to receive a JSON array and print it.

I searched around for a few hours, but I could not find a solution.

Here is, what I have in PHP:

```
<?php

$array = array(
  0 => "test",
  1 => "test1"
);

json_encode($array);

$host = "tcp://localhost";
$port = 8123;
$data = json_encode($array);
$errstr = '';
$errno = '';

if ( ($fp = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 3) ) === FALSE)
    echo "$errstr ($errno)";
else {
    print 'SUCCESS!<br />';
    fwrite($fp, $data);
    while (! feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp, 4096);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

My Java code:

```
public class tcp {

            public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
                String clientSentence;
                String capitalizedSentence;
                ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(8123);

                while (true) {
                    Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
                    BufferedReader inFromClient =
                            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
                    DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
                    clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
                    System.out.println("Received: " + clientSentence);
                    capitalizedSentence = clientSentence.toUpperCase() + '\n';
                    outToClient.writeBytes(capitalizedSentence);
                    connectionSocket.close();
                }
            }

    }
```

So as you should see, I never have done something like this before. 
My questions:

1) Do I have to open port "8123", also when the website and my application will run on localhost (ubuntu / debian)? -> how should I open them correctly?

2) When I start my app, I think I have to create the "tcp" java object. -> `tcp tcp = new tcp` - is this enough or do I have to call a method other something similar?

3) What do I have to change in my code? The Application does just nothing when I send a request...

So I hope you guys can help me with my problem :)
Greets

EDIT:

When I try to run my PHP script, I git following error:

```
Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to tcp://localhost:8123 (Connection refused) in /PATH_TO_PHP/TCPSEND/index.php on line 16
Connection refused (111)
```

Comment: One suggestion: convert this into http / rest

Comment: You mean, I should replace "tcp://" with "http://"?

Comment: No, convert the Java code into a servlet and call its URL from php

Comment: Usually apps initiate the connection with a server (and not the other way around)

Comment: I do not mean an "app", I write a plugin for a game server. When an user changes something in his control panel, the change should also take effect "in game"

Comment: If your java code is running and you can't connect to port 8123 then you probably have problem with firewall. Your java code works fine for me. Try testing with telnet localhost 8123

Comment: @Nemanja how do you use the java code? By writing tcp tcp = new tcp()? Is that all I have to do?

Comment: Just compile java source with javac and run it with java. It will invoke main(String [])  on start-up

Comment: @Nemanja sorry, I don't know what you mean... I'm writing a spongepowered (minecraft) plugin, so I do compile it in Intelliji before I can run it ...